# jquery function not being called from angularJs table

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, frontend, datetimepicker

I am trying to use jQuery datetimepicker plugin [this](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#step) with angularJs in my project.It is working fine if I use it in anywhere other than table but when I am using it in table with 'ng-repeat' it does'nt work.

Html code:

```
<div ng-controller= "thirdCtrl">
    <table style="border: 1px solid;">
        <tr>
            <td>Select Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="actor in AAA.cast>
            <td><input id="datetimepicker{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="actor.date">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Cal" id="image_button{{$index}}" ng-click="cal($index)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
function thirdCtrl($scope)
{
    var AAA = {};    
AAA.cast = [    { 'date' : '20-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'} , 
                { 'date' : '01-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'} , 
                { 'date' : '15-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'} , 
                { 'date' : '30-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'} , 
                { 'date' : '31-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'} , 
                { 'date' : '14-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'} , 
                { 'date' : '11-Dec-2014 7:00 pm'}
               ];

$scope.cal = function(index)
{
  var id = 'datetimepicker'+index;
  console.log('datetimepicker called '+ id);
  jQuery('#id').datetimepicker('show'); //support hide,show and destroy command
};

Date.parseDate = function( input, format ){
  return moment(input,format).toDate();
};
Date.prototype.dateFormat = function( format ){
  return moment(this).format(format);
};

for(var i=0; i< AAA.cast.length; i++)
{
    var temp  = 'datetimepicker'+i;
    console.log('temp '+temp);
  jQuery('#temp').datetimepicker({
  format:'DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a',
  formatTime:'h:mm a',
  formatDate:'DD-MMM-YYYY'
});
}
};
```

When I call this calendar button then 'cal()' mthod is being called but calendar is not being displayed. I have debugged this code many time and all values are being initialized properly and id's are assigned properly. There is no error in JS code and jQuery's `datetimepicker()` method is being called but not displaying the calendar.

Comment: You aren't creating the calendar until the user clicks the submit button... that is a strange way of doing things. `datetimepicker()` only creates a datetimepicker, but it doesn't show it. I would create the datetimepicker during initialization, and the calendar should pop up automatically when the user gives focus to the text box.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid using jQuery in Angular's controllers, the place for jQuery if needed is inside a directive.

Anyway in your code, your function doesn't work because you don't use the right id, 
update your cal method:

```
$scope.cal = function(index)
{
  var id = 'datetimepicker'+index;
  jQuery('#' + id).datetimepicker('show');
};
```

Comment: that is just a typo... I am using the correct id. It's not working.